# The Defined function "mysql_entities_fix_string" in PHP isn't getting called

Tags: php, security, php-5.5, secure-coding

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
require_once 'welcome.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
if(!$db_server) die("Unable to connect with MySql : " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("Unable to connect with db");


echo <<<_END
<form action = 'ps.php' method = 'post'><pre>
Enter your Username <input type = 'text' name = 'username'>
Enter your Password <input type = 'text' name = 'password'>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Cl1ck M3'>
</pre></form>
_END;

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    //echo "Fine till here1";
    echo $_POST['username']."  Without htmlentities <br>";
    $usernameP = mysql_entities_fix_string($_POST['username']);
    if (!$usernameP) die ("No value fetched in the variable usernameP");

    $passwordP = mysql_entities_fix_string($_POST['password']);
    if (!$passwordP) die ("No value fetched in the variable passwordP");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM hacker WHERE username = '$usernameP' AND password = '$passwordP'";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$db_server);
    if(!$result) die ("Unable to execute query : " . mysql_error());

    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        echo $row[0];
        if ($row[0] == '$username' && $row[1] == '$passwordP')
        {
            echo "Credentials Authorized";
        }

   function mysql_entities_fix_string($string)
         {
                return htmlentities(mysql_fix_string($string));
        }   

    function mysql_fix_string($string)
        {
                if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
                return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
         }
    }   
mysql_close($db_server);

?>
```

I'm trying to test a simple PHP page. I'm filtering out malicious input using a function "mysql_entities_fix_string" but the program isn't able to call it. Thus no value is getting fetched in $usernameP or in $passwordP.
Can anyone suggest something ?

Comment: Apart from the conditional-definition problem, this is a misguided approach to input handling. HTML-escaping is a templating output concern, you should be doing it by using `htmlspecialchars` when you `echo` content into HTML markup. SQL-escaping is a query prep concern, which you should be doing when inserting content into an SQL string literal. (Or, better, avoiding the need for SQL-escaping entirely by using parameterised queries in `mysqli` or PDO, and not the deprecated `mysql` function.) You can't do them both in one place, you'll have mangled inconsistent content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the function conditionally. If the function is defined e.g. in an `if` statement, it is only available *after* your code executes over it. In contrast, functions defined in the main scope ("outside all the brackets") are defined before the rest of the file is run.

Comment: I was hazy on if anyone will care to reply. Anyways I'm new with PHP so learning stuff. Got your point. Thumps up @Piskvor