# Cannot get HTML form to set $_POST

Tags: php, html, post

Below is my form build and then the php script where im trying to recieve to data to. No values are getting sent and all variables remain blank. its not server as have had simple form working in exact enviroment.

```
<table class="addbookings" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
    <th colspan="2" align="center">Add Booking</th>
    <form method="post" action="addbooking.php" id="addbookingf">
    <tr><td>Forename</td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="forename"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Surname</td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="surname"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Date</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="date"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Start Time</td>
        <td><input type="time" step="900" name="stime"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Finish Time</td>
        <td><input type="time" step="900" name="ftime"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Contact Number</td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="14" name="number"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address</td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="160" name="address"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="64" name="email"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Quads</td>
        <td><input type="number" min="0" max="300" name="quads" value="0"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Clays</td>
        <td><input type="number" min="0" max="300" name="clays" value="0"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Archery</td>
        <td><input type="number" min="0" max="300" name="archery" value="0"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>4x4</td>
        <td><input type="number" min="0" max="300" name="4x4" value="0"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>MHG</td>
        <td><input type="number" min="0" max="300" name="MHG" value="0"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Team Building</td>
        <td><input type="number" min="0" max="300" name="TB" value="0"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Treasure Hunt</td>
        <td><input type="number" min="0" max="300" name="TH" value="0"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Provisional</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="provisional" value="provisional"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Paid Full</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="paid" value="paid"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Paid Partial</td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="12" name="amountpaid" value="0"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Total Cost</td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="12" name="totalpay" value="0"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Comments</td>
        <td><textarea rows="4"  name="comment" form="addbookingf">Enter any comments here (eg. disabled)</textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="ADD BOOKING"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
```

And below is my receiving addbooking.php

```
$forename = $surname = $number = $address = $email = $comments = ""; 


if(isset($_POST['forename'])) $forename    = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn,$_POST['forename']);
if(isset($_POST['surname'])) $surname      = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn,$_POST['surname']);
if(isset($_POST['date'])) $date            = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn,$_POST['date']);
if(isset($_POST['stime'])) $stime          = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn,$_POST['stime']);
if(isset($_POST['ftime'])) $ftime          = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn,$_POST['ftime']);
if(isset($_POST['number'])) $number        = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn,$_POST['number']);
if(isset($_POST['address'])) $address      = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn,$_POST['address']);
if(isset($_POST['email'])) $email          = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
if(isset($_POST['quads'])) $quads          = $_POST['quads'];
if(isset($_POST['clays'])) $clays          = $_POST['clays'];
if(isset($_POST['archery'])) $archery      = $_POST['archery'];
if(isset($_POST['4x4'])) $fourbyfour       = $_POST['4x4'];
if(isset($_POST['MHG'])) $mhg              = $_POST['MHG'];
if(isset($_POST['TB'])) $tb                = $_POST['TB'];
if(isset($_POST['TH'])) $th                = $_POST['TH'];
if(isset($_POST['provisional'])) $prov     = $_POST['provisional'];
if(isset($_POST['paid'])) $paid            = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn,$_POST['paid']);
if(isset($_POST['amountpaid'])) $ampaid    = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn,$_POST['amountpaid']);
if(isset($_POST['totalpay'])) $total       = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn,$_POST['totalpay']);
if(isset($_POST['comments'])) $comments    = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn,$_POST['comments']);
```

Comment: Did you check `var_dump($_POST);` ? So you can tell if the data is being sent at all.

Comment: What is `mysql_entities_fix_string()`? Any chance it returns `NULL`?

Comment: I checked at my end. `var_dump($_POST);` is returning all the values I entered in the first form.

Comment: You are using a deprecated API mysql_*. Use mysqli_* or PDO and learn about prepared statements. Also check what is returned by $_POST in php page with `print_r($_POST);

Comment: @Mark `var_dump($_POST)` prints `array(0) { }` this means the errors in my form right?

Comment: also, where did you define mysql_entities_fix_string? It is not a standard mysql_* api function. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140947/the-defined-function-mysql-entities-fix-string-in-php-isnt-getting-called) answer on the point.

Comment: `mysql_entities_fix_string()` is a custom method that strips slashes and passes through htmlentities, sorry should have mentioned that, definatly returns correct values.

Comment: @NathanMcnally so temporary get rid of all that functions (you can comment them out) and try to send sample data. Check debugging tools in your browser (sample in Chrome: http://wpscholar.com/blog/view-form-data-in-chrome/ ) if and where it is sent.

Comment: this code begs for a loop

Comment: @Mark Thanks alot! Will do that now!

Comment: What does strip slashes and htmlentities have to do with mysql?

Comment: @NathanMcnally did you manage to solve your problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

No problem in $_POST values. The only problem is in your php function

```
mysql_entities_fix_string(); // Undefined function
```

Use proper php function.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="submit" value="ADD BOOKING">`

This needs to be changed to

`<input type="submit" name="send" value="ADD BOOKING">`

then on the isset line you need to add:

```
if (isset($_POST['send'])){
 //Do something
}
```